# Determine whether changes in a commit are present in another branch or not

Tags: git, diff

What is the best way to determine if the changes made by a commit on a branch are also made in a different commit on other branches or not?
Does `git diff` allows us to determine this?

Comment: Are you asking if the commit itself is present in the other branch, or if the changes made by the commit were also made in a different commit in the other branch?

Comment: The second part, if the changes made by the commit were also made in a different commit in another branch

Comment: That has to be done manually with `git diff`.  There's no automated way to do that.

Comment: You could let git figure that out for you by trying to run the cherry-pick on a branch.... but it's not a bullet-proof approach, I bet there will be plenty of corner cases where you could get false positives/negatives.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`git log --cherry-mark A...B`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-mark), then search for the lines that start with `=`. These are the commits that have been cherry-picked from `A` to `B` or vice versa.

This will discover only commits whose whole changes occur multiple times in the histories, but does not detect parts of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are interested in the actual code change, and that it could be introduced in any commit (not necessarily a cherry-pick or rebase of the same commit)?

If your repository is not enormous, you can do it manually with searching the history with all changes.

`git log -u -a` shows you all commits, with the code changes they introduced. It typically opens a pager, such as `less`.

Once your history is open in `less`, you can search for the specific change you are searching for. In `less`, forward search is `/`, then `n` to find next match.

If `less` scares you, you can save the log output to a file (`git log -u -a > /tmp/the-whole-history`) and search for your change of interest in that file.

You can then make a note of which commits introduced the same change, and analyze that later.

---

If you are interested in finding a cherry-pick of a specific commit, and you can reasonably expect that the commit message was not modified by the user cherry-picking, you can also browse the commit history and search for the commit message.

Use the same trick as above (maybe you don't need the `-u` of `git log`), but with part of the commit message as the search string.

Of course, the first method should still work.

Comment: Actually, I am mainly interested in changes introduced through a cherry-pick. I am looking for git commands which can help me achieve this.

Comment: @toothie: updated. I don't think cherry-pick saves references to the original commit, but if the commit messages was unchanged, you can search for that instead. Or just look for the line in the full log, as I described before.